# Ionic 2 push payload - How to use payload in component

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic2

I'm sending a push notification with Firebase and it works. When I send a payload with the push notification how is possible to read the data from the payload in the component.

When I alert the msg object from the observable it alerts [object, Object]

```
const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
    'core': {
        'app_id': 'fec59dd8'
    },
    'push': {
        'sender_id': '808269516661',
        'pluginConfig': {
            'ios': {
                'badge': true,
                'sound': true
            },
            'android': {
                'iconColor': '#343434',
                'senderID': '808269516661'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the code that subscribes to the push notification

```
this.push.rx.notification()
  .subscribe((msg) => {
    alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);

    if (msg.app.asleep || msg.app.closed) {
      // The app is being opened from a notification
      alert("OPEN APP");
      alert(msg);
      this.rootPage = RetailPage;
    } else {
      // The app was already open when the notification was received
      alert("APP WAS OPEN");
    }
  });
  }
```

Your system information:

ordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.46
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.7.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Any help appreciated

Best regards

Comment: Just use `console.log` to ge the structure of the object or `alert(JSON.stringify(msg))`

Comment: This is why it's good to ask stupid questions :) Thank you very much, this ofcourse worked.

Comment: so what was it? how to retrieve the payload info?